# Как сделать генератор списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код:

```
arr_user_id = []
for msg in messages:
    if msg['from_id'] not in arr_user_id:
        arr_user_id.append(user_id)
```

Как это все уместить в одну строчку?

```
#типа вот так:
arr_user_id = [msg['from_id'] if msg['from_id'] not in messages for msg in messages]
```

Но ошибка:

> Syntax Error.

Как составить правильно генератор?

Comment: `[msg['from_id'] for msg in messages if msg['from_id'] not in arr_user_id]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уточню. Ваш список `arr_user_id` изначально пустой и только по ходу выполнения программы наполняется элементами, так? Если это так, то попробуйте это:

```
arr_user_id=[msg['from_id'] for msg in messages]
arr_user_id=list(set(arr_user_id))
```

Либо совсем уж кратко:

```
arr_user_id=list({msg['from_id'] for msg in messages})
```

Пояснения нужны?

Comment: NameError: free variable 'arr_user_id' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope \n
    arr_user_id = [msg['from_id'] for msg in messages if msg['from_id'] not in arr_user_id]

Comment: Для того, чтобы не совершать `if`-ом проверку на повторы `from_id`, мы просто создаем множество из всех этих адресов. А вся суть множеств состоит в том, что в них каждый элемент уникален. То есть питон выполнит все проверки сам. Далее мы просто изменяем тип с множества на список и все